# Files attachment in PDF file are not opening Adobe Reader

Tags: java, adobe, pdfbox

We are using `pdfbox library` version `2.0.17` and latest `Adobe reader`. We are embedding pdf files to  pdf. The problem is few embeded pdf files are not opening in Adobe reader.

Please refer the link for sample code, sample PDFs and PDF which is have problem in attachments.

Below attachments of PDF not able to open in Adobe Reader. Where i can able to open in `Firefox` and other viewers.

PDF attachments file Name: 10.pdf, 11.pdf and 12.pdf

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X7PzkauqhzChg05u7qmw4OSodmHQqd32/view?usp=sharing

Could some one help out for the issue.

Comment: please try using also `setFileUnicode()` and not only `setFile()` and tell whether that works, so I'll make this an answer. See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4485 and the EmbeddedFiles.java example.

Comment: And don't forget to update to 2.0.18. Use the maven versions plugin if possible.

Comment: Thanks Tilman for reply.

Issues is now resolved after code changes as below.

There was some issue with tree node, so i have removed tree node code which adding node into the tree while embedding files. Please refer the updated code from link.

Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NFerIiMPgIIcZE3PQZLleGW1v4zTZsx6

Comment: Consider answering this yourself, I had a quick look, you didn't use what I wrote in the first comment, so the cause was different. (You should still do it, if you want Android users to view these PDFs)